# in R shiny, how to automatically or based on function tabPanel, given we have 3 levels of lists?

Tags: r, shiny

I need to create conditional 3 levels of tabs the first level or tabPanel includes three tabs 
"NUTS","SWEETS","DRINKS"
so the

`level1<-list(DRINKS,SWEETS,NUTS)`

the second level or is conditional on the first level 
for example after selecting DRINKS, would be juices, energydrinks, hotdrinks
the third level would be after selecting energy drinks to "powerhorse","redbull"

tried code  but not working is this

## lists -------------------------------------------------------------------

```
library(shiny)
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)

hotdrinks<-list('hotdrinks'=list("tea","green tea")) 
juices<-list('juices'=list("orange","mango") )
energydrinks<-list('energydrinks'=list("powerhorse","redbull")) 
drinks<-list('drinks'=list(hotdrinks,juices,energydrinks))
biscuits<-list('bisc'=list("loacker","tuc"))
choc<-list('choc'=list("aftereight","lindt") )
gum<-list('gum'=list("trident","clortes") )
sweets<-list('sweets'=list(gum,juices,energydrinks))

almonds<-list('almonds'=list("salted","roasted") )
pistcio<-list('pistcio'=list("flavourd","roasted")) 
nuts<-list('nuts'=list(almonds,pistcio))

all_products<-list(sweets,nuts,drinks)
mt<-melt(all_products)

mt2<-mt%>%mutate("Price"=c(23,34,23,23,54,32,45,23,12,56,76,34,62,12,98,43),
          "Quantity"=c(10,20,26,22,51,52,45,23,12,56,76,55,62,12,98,43))

t1<-mt2[,c(5,3,1,8,7)]
t1
colnames(t1)<-c("CAT","PN","SP","Quantity","Price")

t2<-list(unique(t1$CAT))
t2
```

## app ---------------------------------------------------------------------

```
library(shiny)

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  observe({print(input$t)})
  observe({print(input$u)})
  observe({print(input$v)})
  t3<-t1%>%filter(t1$CAT==input$t)
  print(t3)
  t4<-list(unique(t3$PN))
  print(t4)
  t5<-t3%>%filter(t3$PN==input$r)
  print(t5)
  t6<-list(unique(t5$SP))
  print(t6)
  t7<-reactive({
         t1%>%filter(t1$CAT==input$t,t1$PN==input$u,t1$SP==inptut$v)
         print(t7())
       })
  output$mytable <- DT::renderDataTable({
         t7
       })

  lapply(1:5, function(j) {
         DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")
       })
}

ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("xxx"),
  sidebarPanel(),
  mainPanel(
    do.call(tabsetPanel, c(id='t',lapply(unlist(t2), function(i) {
  tabPanel(
      do.call(tabsetPanel, c(id='u',lapply(unlist(t4), function(i) {
      tabPanel(
        do.call(tabsetPanel, c(id='v',lapply(unlist(t6), function(i) {
          tabPanel(DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")
              )
        })))

          )
        })))  

      )
    })))

  )
)
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

the manual steps

```
hotdrinks<-list("tea","green tea") 
juices<-list("orange","mango") 
energydrinks<-list("powerhorse","redbull") 
drinks<-list(hotdrinks,juices,energydrinks) 

biscuits<-list("loacker","tuc") 
choc<-list("aftereight","lindt") 
gum<-list("trident","clortes") 
sweets<-list(gum,juices,energydrinks) 

almonds<-list("salted","roasted") 
pistcio<-list("flavourd","roasted") 
nuts<-list(almonds,pistcio) 

all_products<-list(sweets,nuts,drinks)

choc<-  
tabsetPanel(
tabPanel("aftereight"),
tabPanel("lindt")
)
bisc<-  
tabsetPanel(
tabPanel("loacker"),
tabPanel("tuc")
)
gm<-  
tabsetPanel(
tabPanel("trident"),
tabPanel("clortes")
)

hdrinks<-  
tabsetPanel(
tabPanel("tea"),
tabPanel("green tea")
)
jcs<-  
tabsetPanel(
tabPanel("orange"),
tabPanel("mango")
)
ngdrinks<-  
tabsetPanel(
tabPanel("powerhorse"),
tabPanel("redbull")
)

al<-  
tabsetPanel(
tabPanel("salted"),
tabPanel("roasted")
)
pst<-  
tabsetPanel(
tabPanel("flavourd"),
tabPanel("roasted")
)

runApp(list(
ui = shinyUI( fluidPage(

sidebarLayout( 
  sidebarPanel(width = 2),      
  mainPanel(tabsetPanel(id='conditioned',
                        tabPanel("sweets",value=1,
                                 tabsetPanel(
                                   tabPanel("biscuits",
                                            tabsetPanel(bisc)),
                                   tabPanel("choc",
                                            tabsetPanel(choc)),
                                   tabPanel("gum",
                                            tabsetPanel(gm))
                                 )),
                        tabPanel("nuts",value=2,
                                 tabsetPanel(
                                   tabPanel("almonds",
                                            tabsetPanel(al)),
                                   tabPanel("pistcio",
                                            tabsetPanel(pst))
                                 )),

                        tabPanel("drinks",value=3,
                                 tabsetPanel(
                                   tabPanel("hotdrinks",
                                            tabsetPanel(hdrinks)),
                                   tabPanel("juices",
                                            tabsetPanel(jcs)),
                                   tabPanel("energydrinks",
                                            tabsetPanel(ngdrinks))

                                 ))
                        ))
  ))),

 server = function(input, output, session) {}
))
```

as you can see this approach is too vulnerable to mistake, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
hotdrinks<-list("tea","green tea") 
juices<-list("orange","mango") 
energydrinks<-list("powerhorse","redbull") 
drinks<-list("hotdrinks"=hotdrinks, "juices"=juices, "energydrinks"=energydrinks) 

lst_drinks <- lapply(seq_along(drinks), 
                     #browser()
                     #create 2nd level, tab name with the corresponding 3rd level list  
                     function(x) tabPanel(names(drinks[x]),
                                          #create tabsetPanel for hdrinks, jcs, ngdrinks level i.e. 3rd level 
                                          do.call("tabsetPanel", 
                                                  lapply(drinks[[x]], function(y) tabPanel(y))
                                                  )
                                          )
                     )

hdrinks<-  
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("tea"),
    tabPanel("green tea")
  )
jcs<-  
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("orange"),
    tabPanel("mango")
  )
ngdrinks<-  
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("powerhorse"),
    tabPanel("redbull")
  )

runApp(list(
  ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout( 
      sidebarPanel(width = 2),      
      mainPanel(tabsetPanel(id='conditioned',
                            tabPanel("drinks",value=3,
                                     tabsetPanel(
                                       tabPanel("hotdrinks",
                                                #No need for tabsetPanel as hdrinks already has one, therefore I removed it in lapply
                                                tabsetPanel(hdrinks)),
                                       tabPanel("juices",
                                                tabsetPanel(jcs)),
                                       tabPanel("energydrinks",
                                                tabsetPanel(ngdrinks))

                                     )),
                            tabPanel("drinks-test",
                                     do.call("tabsetPanel", lst_drinks))
                                     ))
    ))),

  server = function(input, output, session) {}
))
```

**The Full solution**

```
hotdrinks<-list("tea","green tea") 
juices<-list("orange","mango") 
energydrinks<-list("powerhorse","redbull") 
drinks<-list("hotdrinks"=hotdrinks,"juices"=juices,"energydrinks"=energydrinks) 

biscuits<-list("loacker","tuc") 
choc<-list("aftereight","lindt") 
gum<-list("trident","clortes") 
sweets<-list("gum"=gum,"biscuits"=biscuits,"choc"=choc)

all <- list("drinks"=drinks, "sweets"=sweets)

all_lst <- lapply(seq_along(all), function(z) tabPanel(names(all)[z], 
                                                       do.call("tabsetPanel", 
                                                               lapply(seq_along(all[[z]]), function(x) tabPanel(names(all[[z]][x]), 
                                                                                                                do.call("tabsetPanel", 
                                                                                                                        lapply(all[[z]][[x]], function(y) tabPanel(y, DT::dataTableOutput(y)))
                                                                                                                        )
                                                                                                                )
                                                                      )
                                                               )
                                                       )
                  )

runApp(list(
  ui = shinyUI(fluidPage( 
    sidebarLayout( 
      sidebarPanel(width = 2),      
      mainPanel(do.call("tabsetPanel", c(id='conditioned', all_lst)))
      ))),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    observe({
      nms = unlist(all)
      names(nms) <- sub('\\d', '', names(nms))
      for(i in seq_along(nms)){
        #browser()
        local({
          nm      = nms[i]
          CAT_var = unlist(strsplit(names(nm), '\\.'))[1]
          PN_var  = unlist(strsplit(names(nm), '\\.'))[2]
          SP_var  = nm[[1]]
          output[[SP_var]] <- DT::renderDataTable({filter(t1, CAT==CAT_var, PN==PN_var, SP==SP_var)})
        })
      }
    })
  }
))
```

Comment: Firstly, i didn't your response& prompt like this , thank you very much. secondly where can i insert the datatable output - you can find the full dataframe in the lists section, "t1" thank you again

Comment: as you can see each level of tabs will filter the data in the datatable

Comment: @JohnSmith sorry I didn't notice the DT's part. Here something you can start with, I'm sure someone will come along and propose a better solution.

Comment: Dear @A.Suliman, is there a way solve this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59344173/in-r-how-to-automatically-plots-based-on-lists/59346097#59346097  thanks in advance